# Python data type cannot change in while loop

Tags: python

`data['text']` is a `str`, then I use `data['text'][i] = data['text'][i].split()` to convert it to a list, but in the second while, it is still a str. More strange is that, if I use `data['text'][i] = data['text'][i].split()` in the second while to convert it to a list again, it will *throw an error* in `j == 2,`

> 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

So why the change of the type of `data['text'][i]` will be invalid in the second while?

```
i = 0
while i < len(data['text']):
    data['text'][i] = data['text'][i].split()
    j = 0
    i += 1
    while j < len(data['text'][i]):
        if data['text'][i][j].startswith('@'):
            data['text'][i].remove(data['text'][i][j])
            j -= 1
        data['text'][i][j].strip('#')
        j += 1
```

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'remove'

Comment: There is `i += 1`. After that, `data['text'][i]` refers probably to another object.

Comment: can you add the data= line to your question so we can see what the data looks like?

Answer (score 0):

As also  Michael Butscher stated, you started with `i = 0`, and converted `data['text'][0]` to `list`, but then increased `i` by 1 and tried to use a list method `remove` on `data['text'][1]`, which is not guaranteed to be a list.